# Sketching the solution of an implicit quadratic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, implicit-function

$$G(u,\lambda) = u^2+\lambda^2−9 = 0$$

where $u\in\mathbb{R}$ is the variable of interest and $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$ is treated as a parameter.

How can I sketch the solution branch for the equation in the plane, and state the points on the branch are isolated?

I tried to used implicit function theorem to prove my solution; however, I still not sure about the second question?

Comment: I've cleaned up your question somewhat. In the future, please use Latex to format your math equations: see here for a quick tutorial (https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Also, if you want help from others, please show a minimum level of care in writing your question with proper grammar, complete sentences, capitalized "I," etc.

Comment: $ u= \sqrt{9-\lambda^2}$

Answer (score 0):

The Pythagorean Theorem jumps out of this equation. It is a circle with a radius of $3.\quad$ Here is the circle inscribed with what has the approximate proportions of the well-known $(3,4,5)$ triangle. In fact, the circle represents an infinite set of right triangles with the hypotenuese $(3)$ having one end on the center and one end on the circle.[image]